# Hector & Cassandra issue NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_MEMTABLE_THROUGHPUT_IN_MB

Tags: java, database, nosql, cassandra, hector

I'm testing the connection to Cassandra Database over Hector. But when I run the Junit Tests I constanly get following message:

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_MEMTABLE_THROUGHPUT_IN_MB

Does somebody know what I do wrong?

Thanks for your help,
Chris

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: com.acolsolutions.trademaniac.CreateSchemaTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.287 sec <<< FAILURE!
testAddDropKeyspace(com.acolsolutions.trademaniac.CreateSchemaTest)  Time elapsed: 0.218 sec  <<< ERROR!
**java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_MEMTABLE_THROUGHPUT_IN_MB**
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.ThriftCfDef.<init>(ThriftCfDef.java:119)
    at me.prettyprint.hector.api.factory.HFactory.createColumnFamilyDefinition(HFactory.java:658)
    at com.acolsolutions.trademaniac.CreateSchemaTest.testAddDropKeyspace(CreateSchemaTest.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:53)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
```

And here the Code:

```java
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.acolsolutions.trademaniac;

import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import com.acolsolutions.trademaniac.migrations.Schema;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javassist.NotFoundException;
import me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.CassandraHostConfigurator;
import me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.ThriftCluster;
import me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.ThriftKsDef;
import me.prettyprint.hector.api.ddl.ColumnFamilyDefinition;
import me.prettyprint.hector.api.factory.HFactory;
import org.apache.thrift.TException;
import org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException;

/**
 *
 * @author charms
 */
public class CreateSchemaTest {

  private ThriftCluster cassandraCluster;
  private CassandraHostConfigurator cassandraHostConfigurator;  

  public CreateSchemaTest() {
  }

  @BeforeClass
  public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
  }

  @AfterClass
  public static void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
  }

  @Before
  public void setupCase() throws TTransportException, TException, IllegalArgumentException,
          NotFoundException, UnknownHostException, Exception {
    cassandraHostConfigurator = new CassandraHostConfigurator("localhost:9160");
    cassandraCluster = new ThriftCluster("Test Cluster", cassandraHostConfigurator);
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() {
  }
  // TODO add test methods here.
  // The methods must be annotated with annotation @Test. For example:
  //
  // @Test
  // public void hello() {}
  @Test
  public void testAddDropKeyspace() throws Exception {
    ColumnFamilyDefinition cfDef = HFactory.createColumnFamilyDefinition("DynKeyspace", "DynCf");
    cassandraCluster.addKeyspace(
        new ThriftKsDef("DynKeyspace", "org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy", 1, Arrays.asList(cfDef)));

    String ksid2 = cassandraCluster.dropKeyspace("DynKeyspace");
    assertNotNull(ksid2);

    // Now let's wait for schema agreement.
    cassandraCluster.addKeyspace(new ThriftKsDef("DynKeyspace", "org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy", 1, Arrays.asList(cfDef)), true);
    ksid2 = cassandraCluster.dropKeyspace("DynKeyspace", true);
    assertNotNull(ksid2);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using incompatible versions of Hector and Cassandra. The parameters for tuning memtable flushing (such as DEFAULT_MEMTABLE_THROUGHPUT_IN_MB) have been changed in recent versions to simplify the tuning process.  If you can tell us precisely what versions of Hector and Cassandra you are using, things may become clearer...

Comment: I was using Version 0.8.0-3 from Hector and Cassandra 1.0.7. I changed to 1.0-3. So hopefully it will work now. Thanks for your answer DNA.